# How to get time at higher accuracy than timer tick (15ms) on Windows XP?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have written a C++ program to print the timestamps(or system time) at the start of two events. But the difference between these two times is always a 0 or 15ms. This is because the Windows XP timer updates itself 64 times per second i.e once every 15.625ms. So i don't have a way to know any delay between 0 and 15.625ms.

Is there a way to work around this restriction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you currently get the timestamp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliable high-resolution timer on Windows XP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274873/win32-api-timers/2274896#2274896) and [How can I get the Windows system time with millisecond resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729169/how-can-i-get-the-windows-system-time-with-millisecond-resolution)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338?wa=wsignin1.0) to get a higher resolution.

Comment: + `QueryPerformanceFrequency()`.

Comment: All these time I was using boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time().                      QueryPerformanceCounter + QueryPerformanceFrequency() served the purpose of my code!                                                     Thanks a ton!

Comment: Note that `QueryPerformanceCounter` is not stable over long periods of time. Other past similar questions (duplicates) cover this aspect.